# windows powershell command to display when a particular service got restarted with timestamps

Tags: windows, powershell

I am looking for a windows powershell command to display the time and date when the particular service got restarted, started and stopped.

for example: an apache service got restarted from two days, i want to know the date and the timestamp of apache service when it got started and stopped.

Comment: You're looking...where specifically have you looked?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

First lookup the service process ID

```
$ServicePID = (get-wmiobject win32_service | where { $_.name -eq 'YOURSERVICENAME'}).processID
```

Then lookup the process start time and calculate the timespan from now to then

```
new-timespan -Start (get-process -id $servicepid).starttime -end (get-date) | select totalminutes
```